# how to use parted to create one parition with max size and one 16MB

Tags: partitioning, parted

am trying to figure out how to partition with parted

i want to create 2 partitions

first partition with EXT4 maximum size and one the second partition with 16MB FAT16

Comment: Is this in reference to GNU Parted?

Answer (score 0):

[Paragon Partition Manager 2014 Free Edition](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/download.html) will let you manage, resize and tweak hard drive partitions like that.

I am curious as to why you'd want a 16MB Fat16 partition though?

Any way if you get stuck comment and when I get a chance I'll try to help you move forward.

Comment: am thinking of using parted because its commandline and the reason for the FAT16 partition is that cubieboard2 needs it for firmware

Comment: FYI: i use [aomei partition](http://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-partition-assistant.html) assistant on windows

Comment: Okay, well try it out. If you can't get the file systems you need with it then there is another program (it's a bootable CD which is a pain IMO) but it has a TON of formatting options. So in the least you should be able to set up the partition sizes and locations wit PPM. I have to hunt down the name of that program though for you if PPM doesn't do everything but try it first please and *then* comment back. :-)

Comment: i just check if someone else has some advice on parted, am creating a guide and using parted seem to be a good idea lol @ http://nwgat.net/easily-install-arch-linux-on-your-cubieboard2/